# execlp doenst work when im giving the arguments

Tags: c, exec

why the first execlp doesn't work and the second one its ok.

```
int main(){
   int fd[2];
   int i;
   char** arguments = (char**) malloc(5*sizeof(char*));
   char *line = (char*) malloc(15*sizeof(char));
   char *cfile = (char*) malloc(15*sizeof(char));
   char* token;
   size_t bufsize = 0; 

   for(i = 0;i < 5; i++){
      arguments[i] = (char*) malloc(15*sizeof(char));
   }

   getline(&line, &bufsize, stdin);

   i = 0;
   token = strtok(line,TOK_DELIM);
   while( token != NULL ){
      (arguments)[i] = token;
      strcat((arguments)[i++],"\0");
      token = strtok(NULL,TOK_DELIM_1);
   }

   if( !fork() ){
       execlp((arguments)[1],"show",(arguments)[0],NULL);
       close(fd[0]); close(fd[1]);
   }
   close(fd[0]); close(fd[1]);
   waitpid(0,NULL,0);
   if( !fork() ){
      printf("Executable c file:");
      scanf("%s",cfile);
      execlp(cfile,"show",(arguments)[0],NULL);
      close(fd[0]); close(fd[1]);
   }
   close(fd[0]); close(fd[1]);
   waitpid(0,NULL,0);
   return 0;
}
```

---

As you can see now cfile and arguments are both vuriables(dynamic char array).
To run this main you have to gcc the show file writing gcc -o show show.c
Then when you run the main you have to type (pwd | ./show) pwd is the command that i want to execute and ./show the executable file that i want to use to print the output of pwd.I save what the user types on line and then i parse the arguments on a 2d dynamic array.On the first cell of arguments(dynamic 2d array) i save the command that i want to execute and at the second one the executable file that i want to run.

This is the show file that i want to use:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
char *arg[4];
    printf("Execute commands from other file ...\n");
    arg[0] = "sh";
    arg[1] = "-c";
    arg[2] = argv[1];
    arg[3] = NULL;
    execvp ("/bin/sh", arg);
return 0;
```

}

And you must compile it with the same name as the executable file that you are gonna give on the main programm,for example if you gonna type :pwd | ./show
on main you must compile the show file like this : gcc -o show show.c

Also im using those libs :

- stdlib
- stdio
- unistd
- string
- sys/types
- errno
- sys/stat
- fcntl
- sys/wait

Comment: `execlp()` does not require any of its arguments to be string literals.  It is not clear why your particular use is not working as you expect, and in order for us to help, we need you to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: all i want to make is to give the executable file to execlp from user and not from coder,so user can be albe to execute other c files

Comment: What's in `(*arguments)[1]` ? You need to prove to yourself that what you think is happening is actually happening - so e.g. do `printf("(*arguments)[1] = '%s'\n", (*arguments)[1]);` before your execlp() call, so you can see what's in that variable. Also, if execl() fails, you can, on the very next line after execlp(), call `perror("execlp failed");` and perror will print out why it failed.

Comment: Please turn your puzzle of code fragments into a [mcve].

Comment: @ΣωτηρηςΙωαννιδης, the problem is not that we fail to understand what you are trying to achieve, it is that we don't understand how you are trying to achieve it.  As I said already, `execlp()` does not require any of its arguments to be string literals.  To expand on that, it cannot tell whether the pointers in its argument list point to user-provided data.  It does not attempt to make any such distinction.

Comment: I have allready check what happening with (*arguments)[1], and it has my executable file, it has ./show.This thing i want to put it on execlp

Comment: Okey once more, i want to build my own shell.This program execute bash commands like ls pwd etc. When i type pwd | ./show i want to execute other c programm that i call show and print the output of pwd from here

Comment: execlp doestn return any fail so perror doenst rly help me, also it didnt give me any warning or somethink so i can know what is going wrong

Comment: i write more details up so now maybe you can feel where my problem is, thank you for you time anyway

Comment: and i allready tell you that when im giving the argument to execlp from scanf the code works perfect, file and argument are both variable char*, so why the variable file works and variable argument doesnt??

Comment: ΣωτηρηςΙωαννιδης do *not* post your output as images. Post it like it was code and write "Output" before that section. As @Yunnosch mentioned, you really should create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which will then help the others help you! An MCVE is a laconic program with a `main()` that simulates your problem with as much less information as possible.

Comment: I write so much information cause noone can understand what im trying to say here. But ok im gonna change it to somethik small